# Getting UnboundLocalError, saying that local variable 'width' is referenced before assignment

Tags: python

The Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Asus\OPIXray-dataset\DOAM\data\OPIXray.py", line 138, in __getitem__
    im, gt, h, w, og_im = self.pull_item(index)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\OPIXray-dataset\DOAM\data\OPIXray.py", line 184, in pull_item
    target = self.target_transform(target, width, height, img_id)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'width' referenced before assignment
```

Portion of code where width is used:

```py
def pull_item(self, index):
        img_id = self.ids[index]

        #target = ET.parse(self._annopath % img_id).getroot()

        target = self._annopath % img_id
        #print(target)
        #print(self._imgpath % img_id)
        
        img = cv2.imread(self._imgpath % img_id)
        if img is None:
            img = cv2.imread(self._imgpath1 % img_id)
        if img is None:
            img = cv2.imread(self._imgpath2 % img_id)
        if img is None:
            print('wrong')
        #print()
        #print(self._imgpath2 % img_id)
    

        try:
            height, width, channels = img.shape
        except:
            print(img_id)
        

        

        #print("height: " + str(height) + " ; width : " + str(width) + " ; channels " + str(channels) )
        og_img = img
        #yuv_img = cv2.cvtColor(og_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
        try:
            img = cv2.resize(img,(300,300))
        except:
            print('img_read_error')

        #img = np.concatenate((img,sobel_img),2)
        #print (img_id)
        if self.target_transform is not None:
            target = self.target_transform(target, width, height, img_id)
        '''
        if self.transform is not None:
            target = np.array(target)            
            #print('\n\n\n' + str(target) + '\n\n\n' )
            img, boxes, labels = self.transform(img, target[:, :4], target[:, 4])
            # to rgb
            img = img[:, :, (2, 1, 0)]
            # img = img.transpose(a2, 0, a1)
            target = np.hstack((boxes, np.expand_dims(labels, axis=1)))
        '''
        return torch.from_numpy(img).permute(2, 0, 1), target, height, width, og_img
```

I don't have much experience in python but from what I understand I tried including an else block below the try-except block and included *height, width, channels = img.shape* in that else block but all in vain. What should I do??

Comment: Never post screenshots of code. Post a [mre] that we can copy, paste and execute to replicate the problem.

Comment: a catch-all try-except is ***bad***. please debug your code. review [ask] and [mre].